# Magento logged in user redirected to empty shopping cart page when trying to complete an order

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

When placing an order on my magento store as a logged in user, when I click "complete purchase", i'm redirected to an empty shopping cart page instead of the "order received" success page. The order actually goes through and I get my order confirmation email, but it's confusing for the user to not see "Your Order Has Been Received". It doesn't seem to happen when placing an order as a guest. Any ideas on what would cause that?

Possibly useful info:
-just rebuilt my site on a fresh install of 1.8.1 and imported all my order/customer history.
-placed order through authorize.net payment method

Comment: You can redirect the browser to custom page by firing event.Like check in observer that if order is completed redirect the browser to custom page where you can show custom message.for details please study events and observers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well someone finally found the issue. It was related to nginx config on my server. Apparently the data being sent in the headers was too big. So he added these two lines to the nginx config and it fixed the problem:

```
proxy_buffers 8 16k;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;
```